# reverse elements of list and store as list of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to reverse elements within each dictionary and preserve the same format(list of dictionaries) in the output?

```
a = [{'a1':10,'b1':9},{'d1':10,'c1':9}]
```

Expected output

```
e = [{'b1':9,'a1':10},{'c1':9,'d1':10}]
```

Code i tried:

```
for i in a:
    for dic in i.items():
        e = reversed(dic) # iam stuck here on how to do it
```

Comment: Use OrderedDict. It has method to reverse the order easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one approach using `reversed` inside a `dict` comprehension.

**Ex:**

```
a = [{'a1':10,'b1':9},{'d1':10,'c1':9}]
e = [dict(reversed(list(i.items()))) for i in a]

print(e)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'b1': 9, 'a1': 10}, {'c1': 9, 'd1': 10}]
```